# jQuery If/else statement that adds text to DIV upon successful form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, conditional-statements

I have a form built that works perfectly fine. However, when a message is successfully submitted, the user gets redirected to a new page with the 'success' message I have set up. Instead, I want the success message to be displayed in a div which is placed next to the form, and the form to reset in case the user would like to send another message. Likewise, I am also hoping to have my 'error' message show up in the same div upon failure. Was hoping someone can help with my if/else statement to make this possible.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="contact-area">

<form id="theform" name="theform" method="post" action="feedback.php">
<input type="hidden" name='sendflag' value="send">

<p>
<label for="Name">Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" />
</p>

<p>
<label for="Email">Email:</label>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" />
</p>

<p>
<label for="Message">Message:</label><br />
<textarea name="message" rows="20" cols="20" id="message"></textarea>
</p>

<p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-button" />
</p>

</form>     
</div>

<div class="message">
<p class="submitMessage"></p>
</div>
```

Here's my PHP:

```
<?php

$mail_to_send_to = "myemail@gmail.com";
$your_feedbackmail = "noreply@domain.com";

$sendflag = $_REQUEST['sendflag'];
if ( $sendflag == "send" )
{
$name = $_REQUEST['name'] ;
$email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
$message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;
$headers = "From: $name" . "\r\n" . "Reply-To: $email" . "\r\n" ;
$a = mail( $mail_to_send_to, "Feedback form", $message, $headers );
if ($a)
{
print("Message was sent, you can send another one");
} else {
print("Message wasn't sent, please check that you have changed emails in the bottom");
}
}

?>
```

Comment: I suggest you look into ajax forms and javascript. There is no specific error here, just a "how do I do/show me teh codez"

Comment: I agree with Alastair. It is not difficult what you want, a google for ajax jquery form will give you hundreds of tutorials. Also a search here will provide enough examples to get started and come back if you get stuck on actual bits

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you're looking to never leave a page but rather have a `div` appear or disappear based off of a successful form submission.  If so, it looks like you're going to have to use AJAX.  Luckily, jQuery has this built right in!  I'd suggest something like the following:

```
$.post("url.php", { option1: value1, option2: value2 }, function(data) {
    if(data != '')
        $('#theDiv').html("Success!");
});
```

For more information, [read up on the documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).

Answer (score 0):

Read and follow examples here: [jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

You'll basically do something like this.

```
$.ajax({
  url: /url/to/your/php,
  data: dataObjectPosting
  success: function(data){
    //the data object will have your PHP response;
    $('#divid').text('success message');
  },
  error: function(){
    alert('failure');
  }
});
```

Remember, success simply means HTTP 200, not necessarily that your PHP code ran successfully as you would see it.